# Proper IF ELSE use for specific situation

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I need to translate two different, but related, Excel formulas into SQL to generate the necessary info on a report.

[report for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUyjp.png)

1) Column I is calculating the difference between column C and column D, if there is no value in column D it calculates the difference between column C and column H.

2) Column J is calculating the total of time elapsed between column C and column H, or the total of time between column C and column H minus column D to column E.

First formula is in column I--

```
=TEXT(IF(D3<>"",D3-C3,H3-C3),"H:MM:SS")
```

Second formula is in column J--

```
=TEXT((H3-C3)-(E3-D3), "H:MM:SS")
```

This is what I tried after watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wo3WbUBefZw), I have basically no SQL knowledge... (sub COLUMND/C/H for actual heading names.)--

```
IF COLUMND > 0
    BEGIN
        COLUMND – COLUMNC
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        COLUMNH – COLUMNC
    END
```

I am expecting to have the correct values calculate using SQL and not having to export the report and input an Excel formula.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Edited to add the code I tried.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a case statement, here is how you could calculate Col I :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN StartMeal is not null THEN StartMeal - StartShift
ELSE EndShift - StartShift END AS Difference
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you should share the table definitions because the data type would impact how the data needs to be handled. Here's an example on how to get what you ask. The first part is how you should post your sample data for asking.

```
CREATE TABLE #SampleData(
    EmployeeName    varchar(100),
    ShiftDate       date,
    StartShift      datetime,
    StartMeal       datetime,
    EndMeal         datetime,
    EndShift        datetime)
INSERT INTO #SampleData
VALUES( 'TEST, TEST A', '20190424', '20190424 18:48', NULL, NULL, '20190425 03:04'),
      ( 'TEST, TEST B', '20190425', '20190425 07:00', '20190425 12:59', '20190425 13:57', '20190425 16:03')

SELECT * ,
    CONVERT( time, DATEADD( mi, ISNULL( DATEDIFF(mi, StartShift, StartMeal), DATEDIFF(mi, StartShift, EndShift)), 0)),
    CONVERT( time, DATEADD( mi, DATEDIFF(mi, StartShift, EndShift)- ISNULL(DATEDIFF(mi, StartMeal, EndMeal), 0), 0))
FROM #SampleData
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3da8b/10

SQL Query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, 
               CASE
                 WHEN Startmeal is Null THEN EndShift - StartShift
                 ELSE StartMeal - StartShift
               END,
               8) AS DifferenceBetweenStartAndLunchOrEndTime
FROM MyTest;
```